# Как получить копию элементов в БД?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

У меня есть две модели. Тест кейсы и набор тест кейсов, `Test_Case` и `Test_Suite` соответственно, ну и `Test_Suite` включает в себя список `Test_Case`

Когда я получаю таким образом тест кейсы:

```
Test_Suite suite = new Test_Suite();
suite.all_test_cases = db.Test_Cases.ToList();
```

то все манипуляции в `suite.all_test_cases` влияют  на `db.Test_Cases`

Как получить в модель `Test_Suite` все тест кейсы так, чтобы они не были связаны? Я так понимаю проблема в этом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по структуре Вашей программы из прошлых вопросов, Вам нужно унаследовать классы `StepAndExpRes` и `Test_Case` от интрефейса `ICloneable` и реализовать метод `Clone()`.

```
public class StepAndExpRes : ICloneable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Steps { get; set; }
    public string ExpectedResult { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        StepAndExpRes s = new StepAndExpRes();
        s.ExpectedResult = this.ExpectedResult;
        s.Id = this.Id;
        s.Steps = this.Steps;
        return s;
    }
}
```

Так как  `Test_Case` содержит `List<StepAndExpRes>`, добавим статический класс, который будет содержать метод, клонирующий списки:

```
static class Cloner
{
    public static IList<T> Clone<T>(this IList<T> List) where T : ICloneable
    {
        return List.Select(element => (T)element.Clone()).ToList();
    }
}
```

Тогда класс `Test_Case` будет выглядеть так:

```
public class Test_Case: ICloneable  
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Preconditions { get; set; }
    public List<StepAndExpRes> StepAndExpResults { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public bool check { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        Test_Case t = new Test_Case();
        t.Id = this.Id;
        t.Identifier = this.Identifier;
        t.Title = this.Title;
        t.Preconditions = this.Preconditions;
        t.StepAndExpResults = (List<StepAndExpRes>)Cloner.Clone(this.StepAndExpResults);
        t.Date = this.Date;
        t.Comments = this.Comments;
        t.Summary = this.Summary;
        t.check = this.check;
        return t;
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
suite.all_test_cases = (List<Test_Case>)Cloner.Clone(db.Test_Cases.ToList());
```